# CI3 / Validation always returns false upon initial load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I do not understand why upon load the validation always returns false.  Here is part of my controller:

```
 // load up the validation rules for blog Info form
    $this->config->load('mh_blog_validate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('validate_blog_update'));                                                          
    if ($this->form_validation->run('validate_blog_update') === FALSE) {
        $errors     = array('message'   => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $message    = array('message'   => 'Warning - '.$errors['message'],
                                        'class'     => 'danger',  
                                        );
                     $this->data['alert']   = bootstrap_alert($message);          
    }
```

Here is my validation config from mh_blog_validate:

```
 $config['validate_blog_update'] =  array(
        'title' => array(
            'field' => 'title',
            'label' => '',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|xss_clean|min_length[5]|callback_is_slug_unique_on_update[]',

            'errors' => array(
                'required'      => 'The title cannot be blank.',
                'min_length'    => 'The title must be 5 charaters or more.',
                'is_unique'     => 'The title must be unique.',
                'is_slug_unique_on_update' => 'The new title needs to be unique'
            ),
        ),

        'body' => array(
            'field' => 'body',
            'label' => '',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|xss_clean|min_length[5]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required'    => 'The body cannot be blank',
                'min_length' => 'The body must be 5 charaters or more.',
            )    

        ),
); // end validate_blog_create
```

This is the callback function I use in the validate:

```
function is_slug_unique_on_update() {      
    $new_slug    = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
    if ( $new_slug == $this->input->post('slug')) {
        // no change in slug so update
        // echo "no change in title";
        return TRUE;
    } elseif ( $new_slug !== $this->input->post('slug')) {
        // new slug
        $result = $this->Blog_model->is_slug_unique_on_update($new_slug);
        return $result; // returns FALSE if the title is not unique
    }
}
```

The output I receive in the view is "Warning - " and this is placed in the view:

```
    if (isset($this->data['alert']){
                        echo $this->data['alert'];
                       }
```

I was expecting the validation not to produce an error because I have not submitted the form.  It runs the validation maybe(?) even when I have not submitted the form I think.

+++ new edit +++

Added code below that works and wish to know why mine code doesn't.  I thought my code follows the same pattern, no?
     class Form extends CI_Controller {

```
    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                    array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
            );
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                    $this->load->view('myform');
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->load->view('formsuccess');
            }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you put the validation codes within `if(isset($_POST) ...` conditional?

Comment: No I didn't.  I thought $this->form_validation->run() would check to see if it was posted.  Am i wrong?  I have many forms that don't display FALSE on load without checking to see if the form was posted.

Comment: `$this->form_validation->run()` will run the validation, not when the form is posted. If your validation codes are within the same method with non-validation codes, I suggest you wrap the validation codes in a conditional statement so the validation only applied when the form get posted

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Could you please explain a bit more?  Many thanks.

Comment: He did... Wrap your validation function in the first comment code.

Comment: Hi Alex, I added an edit to the original question.  I have pasted in code that works and wish to know how mine is different?  The code I pasted doesnt show error massages when loading but mine does.  Thanks!

Comment: You should read the form validation library docs. You can echo validation_errors() to find out what is triggering and your callback should set an error message regardless. It would help if you posted your whole controller code instead of sections as it's hard to tell context surrounding.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I echo the validation errors but there is nothing!  I only get WARNING which is the consequence of assigning this text to a var (see code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are setting `$this->data['alert']` values, whether the form is submitting data or not. Of course you could prevent this variable assignment by adding conditional so it will set only when there are any `$_POST` data is submitted :

```
// load up the validation rules for blog Info form
$this->config->load('mh_blog_validate');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('validate_blog_update'));                                                          
if ($this->form_validation->run('validate_blog_update') === FALSE) {
    if ($_POST)
    {
        $errors     = array('message'   => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $message    = array('message'   => 'Warning - '.$errors['message'],
                                        'class'     => 'danger',  
                                        );
                    $this->data['alert']   = bootstrap_alert($message);          
    }
}
```

Comment: form validation setup and rules should be **within** `if(isset($_POST))` otherwise its just a waste of resources

Comment: Thank you.  How can I find out why $this->form_validation->run('validate_blog_update') equates to FALSE?  I can't see what is giving it false.

Comment: @spreaderman by default it returned false, no action needed for it to return FALSE, because it catch no data.

Comment: @alex I just narrow it down to where the error are getting triggered

Comment: Thank you Alex.  All makes sense now.  Much appreciated!